# Python selecting variables based on condition

Tags: python, variables, naming, assign, simpy

I'm wondering whether it is possible to select a variable based on a certain condition/input.

For example:

```
day_1 = 5
day_2 = 10
day_3 = 15
i =2
selected_variable = day_i
```

The code would give an error that of course day_i is not defined.
I know I could add all variables to a list and access them through list locations etc but I'm working with a rather big Simpy environment in which this would be very useful if it exists.

Thanks!

Comment: You can use a dictionary in which keys are the variable names and values its values. Then `dict_object.get("day_" + str(i), "No key found") `

Comment: or an IF statement

Comment: I don't understand why a list is unsuitable.

Comment: use a list or a dict for these variables.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `vars()` to get all varables in the scope.

for exsample:

```
day_1 = 5
day_2 = 10
day_3 = 15
i = 2
selected_variable = vars()[f"day_{i}"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can stores the values in a list, and use `i` as an index to access one box, you do `i-1` because list are indexed from 0

```
days = [5, 10, 15]
i = 2
selected_variable = days[i - 1]
```

You can also associated key/value in a dictionary, and from a number get the value

```
days = {
    1: 5, 2: 10, 3: 15
}
i = 2
selected_variable = days[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments there are couple of sulutions:

You can define a dict:

```py
day = {
"day_1": 5,
"day_2": = 10,
"day_3": = 15
}

selected_variable = day[f"day_{i}"]
```

An array

```py
day = [
5,
10,
15
]

selected_variable = day[i]
```

An If statement

```py
day_1 = 5
day_2 = 10
day_3 = 15

if i == 1:
    selected_variable = day_1
elif i == 2:
    selected_variable = day_2
elif i == 3:
    selected_variable = day_3
```

Or the `locals` (or `vars`) dict (my favorite in this case)

```
day_1 = 5
day_2 = 10
day_3 = 15

selected_variable = locals()[f"day_{i}"]
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code will print out the value of the variable `day_2`

```
i =2
selected_variable = 'day_{}'.format(str(i))
exec("print(%s)" % selected_variable)
```