# How can I store a value from a list, after user input select's which list to use?

Tags: python

I want the user to type in a name, then I want to proceed by using specific values based on that input. My current solution is this:

```
model = input("Attacking Model:")
unit = float(input("How many " + str(model) +"'s:"))

if model == "Warrior":
    bal_Shot = unit * 3
    bal_Skill = (4/6)
    bal_Str = 5
    bal_AP = 2
    bal_Dam = 1
elif model == 'Ravener':
    bal_Shot = unit * 5
    bal_Skill = (4/6)
    bal_Str = 5
    bal_AP = 2
    bal_Dam = 1
```

However, once I start adding more model names it is going to start to look messy, and I'm assuming there is a more efficient way to do this.

Another solution I have played around with is creating a list for each, then attempting to set the variables to an index of a user inputted list.

```
model = input("Attacking Model:")

warrior=[3, (4/6), 5, 2, 1]
ravener=[5, (4/6), 5, 2, 1]

bal_Shot = model[0]
bal_Skill = model[1] 
bal_Str = model[2]
bal_AP = model[3]
bal_Dam = model[4]

print(bal_Shot)
```

But when I do this, it is just returning the letter of the input based on index.

Is it possible to return the correct values based on user input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put your `ẁarrior` and `ravener` lists into a dictionary, then you can simply get the corresponding values with a dictionary lookup:

```py
model = input("Attacking Model:")

lookup = {
  "warrior": [3, 4 / 6, 5, 2, 1]
  "ravener": [5, 4 / 6, 5, 2, 1]
}

bal_Shot = lookup[model][0]
bal_Skill = lookup[model][1]
bal_Str = lookup[model][2]
bal_AP = lookup[model][3]
bal_Dam = lookup[model][4]

print(bal_Shot)
```

It might make sense to check whether the entered model name actually exists in the lookup dictioary, else you'll get a `KeyError` if the user enters a model name that doesn't exist in the ´ĺookup`:

```py
model = input("Attacking Model: ")

lookup = {
  "warrior": [3, 4 / 6, 5, 2, 1]
  "ravener": [5, 4 / 6, 5, 2, 1]
}
while model not in lookup: # equivalent to "while model not in lookup.keys()"
  model = input("The model name you entered does not exist - please try again: )

bal_Shot = lookup[model][0]
bal_Skill = lookup[model][1]
bal_Str = lookup[model][2]
bal_AP = lookup[model][3]
bal_Dam = lookup[model][4]

print(bal_Shot)
```

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you are making a confusion between a variable value and a variable name. If the variable named `model` contains the value `warrior,` it does not mean that you can use `model[0]` and expect python to interpret it as `warrior[O]`. I see two possible solutions to your problem.

If you know enough about object-oriented programming, I suggest you make the warrior and ravener two instances of the same class (maybe Character). You can then have a list of all your characters that you can iterate on and check if the character type is the same as the value of your `model` variable entered by the user.

If not, you can select the correct variable using the value entered by the user with `vars()` that returns a dictionary of all variables in scope (among other things). See this post [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60827488/python-selecting-variables-based-on-condition) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

A good approach is to use [dict](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries):

```
model = input("Attacking Model:")

objects = {"warrior":
    {"ball_shot": 3,
    "ball_Skill": (4/6)
},
"ravener":{
    "ball_shot": 5,
    "ball_Skill": (4/6)
}}

if model in objects.keys():
    print(objects[model])
else:
    print("Attacking model doesn't exist !")
```

You can display the result as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

Use a dictionary: you can select which fighter it is:

```py
model = input("Attacking Model:")

fighters = {"warrior": [3, (4/6), 5, 2, 1],
            "ravener": [5, (4/6), 5, 2, 1]}

bal_Shot = fighters[model][0]
bal_Skill = fighters[model][1]
bal_Str = fighters[model][2]
bal_AP = fighters[model][3]
bal_Dam = fighters[model][4]

print(bal_Shot)
```

Note: If the input is bad, you can use a try/except block:

```py
try:
   bal_Shot = fighters[model][0]
   bal_Skill = fighters[model][1]
   bal_Str = fighters[model][2]
   bal_AP = fighters[model][3]
   bal_Dam = fighters[model][4]
except:
   model = input("Attacking Model:")

   bal_Shot = fighters[model][0]
   bal_Skill = fighters[model][1]
   bal_Str = fighters[model][2]
   bal_AP = fighters[model][3]
   bal_Dam = fighters[model][4]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use nested dictionary:

```
Class = { 'Warrior':
             {'bal_Shot': 3, 'bal_skill': (5/6), 'bal_str': 5, 'bal_AP': 2, 'bal_Dam': 1},
          'Ravener':
             {'bal_Shot': 5, 'bal_skill': (4/6), 'bal_str': 5, 'bal_AP': 2, 'bal_Dam': 1}
         }

model = input("Attacking Model: ")
if model in Class:
    unit = float(input("How many " + str(model) + "'s: "))
    bal_Shot = unit * Class[model]['bal_Shot']
    print(f'{model} {bal_Shot = }')
else:
    print('Invalid Attacking Model')

# Attacking Model: Warrior
# How many Warrior's: 2
# Warrior bal_Shot = 6.0

# Attacking Model: Ravener
# How many Ravener's: 3
# Ravener bal_Shot = 15.0

# Attacking Model: Narator
# Invalid Attacking Model
```